# Repeated Pattern

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Can someone suggest how a pattern would be constructed to extract the first list of contiguous numbers from this data?

```
sample = {52.2624, 54.4003, 60.7418, 61.3801, 62.6397, 61.7992,
   63.2282, "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 62.3921, 61.897,
   60.299, 59.053, 61.3778, 64.3724, 63.4251, 78.1912, 79.7451,
   80.4741, "", 81.324, 79.9114, 93.7509};
```

I have tried variations like `sample //. {useable : _?NumberQ .., ___} -> {useable}` to no avail.

`useable = TakeWhile[sample, NumberQ]` works well, but I would like to know how to do it using pattern matching.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trying to preserve your logic:

```
 sample /. {useable : Longest[_?NumberQ ..], ___} -> {useable}
```

If you want the longest numeric sequence:

```
sample /. {___, useable : Longest[_?NumberQ ..], ___} -> {useable}
```

**Edit**

To get all the numeric sequences:

```
Cases[SplitBy[sample, NumberQ], {_?NumberQ ..}]
```

or

```
Last@Reap[sample //. {x___, useable : Longest[_?NumberQ ..], y___} :> 
                                              (Sow@{useable}; {x}~Join~{y})]
```

Answer (score 7):

Another option would be to look for the first non-number entry:

```
sample /. {useable___, _?(!NumberQ[#]&), ___} :> {useable}
```

Comment: +1. Could use `Except[_?NumberQ]` in place of `_?(!NumberQ[#]&)` as well.

Answer (score 6):

One way would be

```
sample /. {Longest[useable___?NumberQ], ___} :> {useable}
```

which returns `{52.2624, 54.4003, 60.7418, 61.3801, 62.6397, 61.7992, 63.2282}` from your sample.